# Plink working directory

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, plink

> MY SERVER: BitVise SSH server for windows
>
> My Client: plink.exe

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to change a directory when using plink.exe and execute a script in that directory.

I am doing something like this to try and send a command to switch a directory and execute a script:

```
C:\plink.exe -ssh 10.10.10.10 -P 22 -l user -pw password cd C:\sample && install.bat
```

However, my command fails each time I run this, stating that install.bat does not exist. If I use putty, connect with the GUI, and run the cd C:\sample && install.bat command, everything works as expected.

Is it possible to tell plink what directory to connect to?

Comment: Since `&` is a command separator in `cmd`, did you put your command in quotes? I would bet that it is trying to run `cd C:\sample` on the server and `install.bat` locally.

Comment: @DarkFalcon ah you are right. post it as the answer so I can mark it as done. TY! I hate windows ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `&` is a command separator in `cmd`, did you put your command in quotes? I would bet that it is trying to run `cd C:\sample` on the server and `install.bat` locally.

```
C:\plink.exe -ssh 10.10.10.10 -P 22 -l user -pw password "cd C:\sample && install.bat"
```